# Laravel vagrant error

Tags: laravel, vagrant, composer-php

I cloned a git repository and did `composer install` and `vagrant up`. When I run the application in the browser I am getting this error:

[image]

When I use the vagrant up command at the end of the process it gives me this:

[image]

The application works perfectly when my partner did exactly the same things I did. Can you guys help me?

Comment: remove all the lines from bootstrap/cache/compiled.php and then run "composer install"

Comment: I edited the picture, I have another error now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem myself, in this particular case I had to reinstall my virtualbox because it was outdated

Answer (score 1):

That could be due to a recent change in Composer.

You may want to have a look at https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/3687.

The simplest way to fix this issue is to apply the changes of the above pull request to your `composer.json` file:

Replace:

```
"pre-update-cmd": [
    "php artisan clear-compiled"
],
"post-update-cmd": [
    "php artisan optimize"
]
```

With:

```
"post-update-cmd": [
    "php artisan clear-compiled",
    "php artisan optimize"
]
```

Laravel 5.2.25 (2016-03-24) introduced more isolated scripts, which you can use as so:

```
"post-install-cmd": [
    "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
    "php artisan optimize"
],
"post-update-cmd": [
    "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
    "php artisan optimize"
]
```

Refs: [laravel/framework#12827](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/12827) - [laravel/laravel#3699](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/3699)

Comment: My composer.json was allready looked like this but I copy pasted it anyway and I get another error: http://i.imgur.com/bAuVDhW.png

Comment: remove full vendor folder,then run "composer install"

Answer (score -1):

It might not have any connection to it, but it happened to me several times that I installed composer to my parent directory named "Code", and not in the actual project directory, and than I would get errors like that.

Comment: that's not the problem :p